# Blazor <img> element showing old source during load of new source

Tags: html, image, blazor

Sometimes it takes up to 5 seconds to load a new source into that same image control, during which time the old image is shown.  Is there a way to clear it or have it revert to the background (which is a loading gif) during that time of loading the new source?

Here is the code:

```
<img class="attachment" src="@url" type="image/jpeg" />
```

So when @url is changed, it loads the new image but keeps the previous image visible during the loading time.

This is invoked by the change of a paremeter by another blazor component:

```
[Parameter]
public ImageInfo ImageInfo { get; set; } = default!;

private string url => ImageInfo.GetImageUrl;
```

... and the parent component instigates this by setting `ImageInfo` when an area is clicked - and then calling `StateHasChanged()`:

```
<div class="next-image" @onclick="() => ShowNextImage()">

<div class="loading">
    <ImageViewer ImageInfo="_currentImage" />
</div>

private void ShowNextImage()
{
    _currentImage = GetNextImage(); // gets the next, this works, and has a valid URL inside, this isn't the issue - it shows, it just takes time to load and during that time, the previous image is shown 

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

For info, the css here:

```
.loading {
    background: transparent url(./loading.gif) no-repeat scroll center center;
}
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: What is `GetImageUrl` and why are there no `()` ?

Comment: @HH it's a property and yes, it probably is badly named.  it returns a valid URL.

Comment: Then show us more of the flow around _"the parent component instigates ..."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting an empty or null state to _currentImage before the GetNextImage() method is called.

```cs
private async Task ShowNextImage()
{
    _currentImage = null;
    await Task.Delay(1); // might or might not need this
    _currentImage = GetNextImage(); 
}
```

Then modify your `ImageViewer` component to handle nullable a `ImageInfo?`

```
@if(ImageInfo is not null){
    <img class="attachment" src="@url" type="image/jpeg"/>
}

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public ImageInfo? ImageInfo { get; set; }
    private string url => ImageInfo?.GetImageUrl ?? "";
}
```

Comment: Ahah my answer is like 17 seconds late, but I'm glad we have the same idea

Comment: @DylanElBar  likewise.

Comment: the working code in the end didn't require a nullable but setting to null and using `src="data:,` as the `<img>` source when null did the trick ... this answer prompted me to do that so marking correct

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. I'm just adding that you don't need to deal with nullability and modify existing variables; you can just introduce a new "refresh" boolean that decides the inclusion of the `<img>` tag (i.e. instead of your `@if(ImageInfo is not null)` statement). This boolean can simply be briefly set to false, then to true, and the image will correctly refresh.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you can achieve what you want (be back to the loading background css) by actually doing the following:

```
[Parameter]
public ImageInfo ImageInfo { get; set; } = default!;

-->

[Parameter]
public ImageInfo? ImageInfo { get; set; }

---------------------------

<img class="attachment" src="@url" type="image/jpeg" />

--> 

@if(ImageInfo is not null) 
{
   <img class="attachment" src="@url" type="image/jpeg" />
}

---------------------------

private void ShowNextImage()
{
    _currentImage = GetNextImage(); // gets the next, this works, and has a valid URL inside, this isn't the issue - it shows, it just takes time to load and during that time, the previous image is shown 

    StateHasChanged();
}

-->

private void ShowNextImage()
{
    _currentImage = null;
    StateHasChanged();  // maybe useless, because normally changing the value of a parameter will automatically call StateHasChanged in Blazor
    _currentImage = GetNextImage();
}
```

By doing that, you un assign the image, it will then no longer display the `<img />` tag, so the loading background css will be visible, then you will trigger the loading of the image, and it will be displayed when loaded.

Comment: StateHasChanged() is indeed useless, but a Delay(1) might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Others proposed a solution that temporarily sets to `null` the `ImageInfo` parameter, which worked for me, but it added some burden in having to deal with nullability checks that cascaded across my code.

A simpler, equivalent solution is to just introduce a new `refresh` boolean that decides on the inclusion of the image tag, i.e.:

```html
<div class="loading">
    @if (!refresh)
    {
        <ImageViewer ImageInfo="_currentImage" />
    }
</div>
```

This boolean can simply be briefly set to `false`, then to `true`, and the image will correctly refresh. E.g.:

```cs
private async Task ShowNextImage()
{
    // Briefly set the refresh bool to true to ensure update of image src.
    refresh = true;
    await Task.Delay(1);
    refresh = false;

    _currentImage = GetNextImage();
}
```

This way, you just introduce a new variable without having to refactor any existing part of the code for nullability checks.